# Conflict between the search function and the global $post object when trying to add a filter to add a class in the body in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, search, filter

Here's my problem.

I want to add a class to the `body` tag of a post or page if the post/page is a child of another post.

So far so good:

```
function add_class_to_custom_post_parent($classes) {

    global $post;
    if ($post->post_parent > 0) {
        $classes[] = 'children-custom-post-page';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_class_to_custom_post_parent' );
```

And it works like a charm but when I use the search function within WordPress (when I try to return all the post or page base on a word), the system still works but it throws this error:

> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in functions.php on line 301

In order to debug it, I tried a different solutions:

I wrapped the code in a conditional `if (is_page()) {}` but then the code won't work in post (and I don't think it's the right solution) and I tried to `var_dump()` the global `$post` object, but for some reason in that page it won't return anything.

So now I'm trying to suspect that there's something wrong.

The thing is that I use a plain theme, so no addition or extra plugin, it's a vanilla version of WordPress and I wrote all the functions.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [is_singular()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) function to add your CSS class to the `body` tag only for posts and pages (and even custom post types as well if you specify them):

```
function add_class_to_custom_post_parent($classes) {

    if ( is_singular(array('post', 'page')) ) {
        global $post;

        if ($post->post_parent > 0) {
            $classes[] = 'children-custom-post-page';
        }
    }

    return $classes;

}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_class_to_custom_post_parent' );
```

Oh, and the reason why you're getting that PHP notice is because `$post` isn't set when you're doing a search: you're not seeing a post nor a page, you're seeing the search results template which doesn't set a `$post` object for itself.

Comment: Actually, I get the problem: I should have added a detail, which is that WordPress throws that error only if the get request will be empty. If the search will return anything, that error won't be thrown. Your solution is clever and it should be good in this case, but I'm not sure if it is the solution of my problem. I tried a conditional though to fire the function only if the global $post object won't be empty, but it will throw some other errors

Comment: Plus, for some reason, the code that you suggested doesn't work on custom posts

Comment: If you're talking about Custom Post Types, then all you need to do is add your CPT to the IF clause as I mentioned above ("**and even custom post types as well if you specify them**"): `if ( is_singular(array('post', 'page', 'my-custom-post-type')) ) {`.

Comment: I guess that the right approach would be:

function add_class_to_custom_post_parent($classes) {

    global $post;

    if (!isset($post)) {
       return [];
    }

    if ($post->post_parent > 0) {
        $classes[] = 'children-custom-post-page';
    }
    return $classes;


}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_class_to_custom_post_parent' );

Comment: If you return an empty array, the `body` tag will have an empty `class` attribute which might not be what you want. In that case, just return the original `$classes` array instead.